# Eclipse. Overwriting Include Patchs from outside the IDE?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, include-path

is there a possibility to overwrite the Include Paths from the command shell without opening the Eclipse IDE ? 
When I Export the Include Paths to an XML file over the GUI and want to import them again, maybe to another project in another workspace so the new ".cproject" file is updated with my own "exportedIncludePaths.xml".

I was not able to find any command from the CDT which could handle that.

Last chance would be to write a script for that, but in best case I can hopefully avoid that.

Thank you in advance